# Monitoring snmp with Nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios, snmp, cpu-usage

I'm using `Nagios` 4 and installed `nagios plugins` to. I wan't to monitor my HP switch ***CPU, MEM, etc via snmp***, but I totally don't know how to do it.
First of all, how do I get the right OID's and how to put it into the `command.cfg` and my `own cfg's`

Attached some pictures.

Thank you!

[command.cfg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYrJH.jpg)
[switch.cfg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wst96.jpg)

Comment: This is a poor question for a Q+A format site. What you're asking for is a guide on how to do this, not help with a specific problem that you've already put research effort into. Consider searching around first, as there are many results similar to this one: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/monitoring-routers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good thing about nagios style monitoring systems (I prefer Icinga2, personally), is that it is very simple to write your own plugins. The state is given be the exit code:

```
0: OK
1: WARNING
2: CRITICAL
3: UNKNOWN
```

Output is simply output on the shell. So a simple `echo` for bash would do.

To get perfdata you append a pipe and a space-seperated list of key value pairs to your output like so:

```
This is an example output | value1=1 value2=2
```

For checking SNMP you can use a shell command like `snmpwalk`. If you don't want to write this from scratch I happen to have written a couple SNMP based checks:

https://github.com/c-store/icinga2checks/tree/master/snmpChecks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor something with nagios using SNMP, you should start by looking at [Nagios Exchange website](https://exchange.nagios.org). It's a nice place to find some command usable in nagios or nagios inspired products (Centreon, Icinga, Shinken)

Look for you specific HP product model in the database, you should find some help on this website.

Good luck!

Arnaud Léonard